# How to fix a NoClassDefFoundError with JMeter in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to execute JMeter Test from Eclipse (https://blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui), 
unfortunately I have this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/jmeter/engine/StandardJMeterEngine
```

This is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
    JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("D:/JMeter_eng/bin/jmeter.properties");
    JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("D:/JMeter_eng");
    JMeterUtils.initLocale();
    SaveService.loadProperties();
    // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
    FileInputStream in = new    FileInputStream("D:/projects/TestJmeterwithCodeJ.jmx");
    HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
    in.close();
    jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
    jmeter.run();

}
```

Comment: Yes, they are my import import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;

import java.io.FileInputStream;

Comment: yes, i have import the jar from /lib and /lib/ext

Comment: thank you, i will wait for your post

Comment: have you had any luck?

Comment: unfortunately not Yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not immediately clear from your description how to solve this error, this is a common problem.  [This link](http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html) is a good resource for debugging this error, but I'll list the essentials from the link here as well.

### What is NoClassDefFoundError?

> A NoClassDefFoundError is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine or a ClassLoader instance tries to load in the definition of a class ... and no definition of the class could be found.  In simple words, the class was available at compile time but missing during runtime.

### NoClassDefFoundError caused By ClassNotFoundException

This means that jar file(s) missing from classpath.  Check to make sure that the .jar files that you compiled your code with are present in the class path in the environment which you are running your application.

Also check if a dependent jar is missing which is not allowing the class constructor to initialize the class object.  Look at the stack trace to find a class in a recursive dependency of your direct dependency (in your case, the direct dependency is `StandardJMeterEngine`)

### NoClassDefFoundError caused by an ExceptionInInitializerError

> When you see NoClassDefFoundError with an ExceptionInInitializerError in stack trace then a dependent class initialization has failed. NoClassDefFoundError is just a symptom. The actual issue is ExceptionInInitializerError which we need to find and fix.

This means that you are passing in invalid parameters to the constructor and the class isn't handling them properly and throws an unexpected exception, or there is some other bug in the internal class.  To fix it either change the source code of your dependency and re-compile it (if it's a third party dependency you may be out of luck) or work around it by passing in different parameters which do not cause the issue.